# all the ways X integers can be summed to make another integer Y

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to know how to find all the ways X non-negative integers can be summed to make another positive integer Y. The order is important, so:

$4=0+1+1+2$ is distinct from $4=2+1+1+0$

I understand this is related to combinatorics but I have never studied this and its new to me.

I have found some material on how to find the number of ways but I need to know the specific combinations.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, yeah I've seen this and could use it calculate the number of ways but I need a method to generate them.

Answer (score 0):

The OP doesn't say how to deal with zeroes, so I'm guessing you can only have one zero in the sum (since OP has an example with a zero).

To generate the tuples:

Using $k$ to mean the size of tuples, where each tuple sums to $Y$, for $k=2$ you have the pairs $(0,Y),(1,Y-1),...(Y,0)$.

For $k=3$ you have all the pairs for $k=2$, but with a zero inserted, before, between, and after the pairs PLUS you have all the tuples $k=2$ with $Y-1$ instead of $Y$, with a 1 inserted in the three different places, and so forth until you are inserting $Y$ among two zeroes. Subsequently or concurrently you'd need to eliminate any triple with consecutive zeroes (again, I'm guessing what the OP's intention is) and other cases that are not considered by OP as distinct.

For $k=4$, you'd use a similar method, starting with the set of triples.

And so on until you get to Y+1-tuples, which would be of the form $(0,1,1,1...),(1,0,1,1,...),...,(...,1,1,0)$

Comment: Thanks for answer, actually you can have up to X - 1 zeroes. They can be consecutive or not.

Comment: Did this answer your question (with the modification you indicated)?

Comment: Still working on the problem but yes i found this helpful.